# CoffeeScript RegEx ListComprehension with Dictionary-Object / Array

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript

**Code**

```
list = {}
list['blubber'] = 'it blubbers'
list['Bearmattazz'] = 'Honey'
document.write list.blubber

result = (item for item in list when item.match(/(mattazz)/g))
document.write '<br>Res: ', result
```

**Pen**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVrwKO

**Want**

I want to regEx for `mattazz`, e.g. retrieve the value "Honey", in case `mattazz` key is in `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate through an **object**, but your coffee syntax is for **array iteration**. You need the **`of`** keyword for that. (See [Coffescript.org: Loops and Comprehensions](http://coffeescript.org/#loops))

`list` is an object (as in key, value store), so you want to use `key, value of list` :

```
list = {}
list['Bearmattazz'] = 'Honey'

# in case you want to retrieve value
#
result = (value for key, value of list when key.match(/(mattazz)/g))

# in case you want to retrieve key
#
result = (key for key, value of list when key.match(/(mattazz)/g))

document.write '<br>Res: ', result
```

Comment: I'd use `key for own key, value of list` just for the sake of not property bubbling where it isn't needed

Comment: What do you mean by bubbling? Bubbling down the object nesting in case there is any?